# Get a user claim in asp.net mvc 4 razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I get a claim, given its type, of the current authenticate user in a Razor view?

I tried a few options, such as the following, but with no success:

```
(ClaimsPrincipal)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); }
```

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try casting to ClaimsIdentity.  This works in my MVC5 project.

```
        @{
        var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

        if (claimsIdentity != null)
        {
            var c = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            if (c != null)
            {
             <p>
                 @c.Type.ToString(); 
                 @c.Value.ToString();
             </p>   
            }
        }
    }
```